# Swift .insert in database entry

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I used this swift code to add the area code and company prenumber to my database entries. Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore with new Xcode version 11.3.1 . Swift Version for this project is 4. 
After I ran the app and login the app crashes. The error appears after the insert of "+" in the code.
Debug:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: String index is out of bounds

```
if cutNumber.lowercased().contains("XXX".lowercased()) { // check if 'cutNumber' contains 'über'
    cutNumber.insert("+", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)) 
    cutNumber.insert("4", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 6))
    cutNumber.insert("9", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
    cutNumber.insert("1", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 8))
    cutNumber.insert("2", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 9))
    cutNumber.insert("3", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 10))
    cutNumber.insert("4", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 11))
    cutNumber.insert("5", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 12))
    cutNumber.insert("6", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 13))
}
else if cutNumber.lowercased().contains("YYY".lowercased()) { 
    cutNumber = "" // set 'cutNumber' to ''
}
else if cutNumber == "" { // check if 'cutNumber' is ''
}
else {
    cutNumber.insert("+", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)) 
    cutNumber.insert("4", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
    cutNumber.insert("9", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))
    cutNumber.insert("1", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 3))
    cutNumber.insert("2", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
    cutNumber.insert("3", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
    cutNumber.insert("4", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 6))
    cutNumber.insert("5", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
    cutNumber.insert("6", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 8))
}
```

Comment: You get this error if the length of `cutNumber` is < 5. By the way you can insert the entire phone number in one line. `let startIndex = cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)` and `cutNumber.insert(contentsOf: "+49123456", at: startIndex)`

Comment: I used your code as suggested  `cutNumber.insert(contentsOf: "+49123456", at: startIndex)`  the output in the app is XXXX+49123456 7890. but it needs to look like this XXXX +491234567890 when i try to call that number the app crashes

Comment: You have to calculate the start index properly.

Comment: i changed the index aswell `if cutNumber.lowercased().contains("XXXX".lowercased()) { cutNumber.insert(contentsOf: "+49123456", at: cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)) }` but that's why `offsetBy:5` was used. to generate the gap between XXXX and +49123456.

Comment: According to your previous comment the offset is supposed to be 5. Or insert a fixed space character at the beginning to the phone number string (`" +49123456"`)

Comment: Yes but that was the problem where it crashed, when I use a offset of 4 it works but I miss the gap between XXXX and the area code

Comment: so I got that problem solved aswell, `cutNumber = cutNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")` I use that before I add the area code and this works for me. If you have a better solution let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I realised here is that in the first if you are trying to insert within an `offsetBy: 5`,  if your string doesn't have 5 characters, it will always crash, because it will be out out of bounds

I think you will need to prevent that, if checking if it has a minimum of 5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
if cutNumber.lowercased().contains("XXXX".lowercased()) { 
    cutNumber = cutNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    cutNumber.insert(contentsOf: " +123456",at:cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
}
else if cutNumber.lowercased().contains("Funk".lowercased()) {
        cutNumber = ""
}
else if cutNumber == "" {
}
else {
       cutNumber.insert(contentsOf: " +49721599",at:cutNumber.index(cutNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 0))
       cutNumber = cutNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
}
```